# Show the convergent of sequences and limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

a)Show that the following sequence of functions is convergent.

$f_{1}(x) = \sin(x)$

$f_{2}(x) = \sin(\sin(x))$

$f_{3}(x) = \sin(\sin(\sin(x)))$

...

$f_{n}(x) = \sin(\sin(\sin(...(\sin(x))))$ ($n$ times)

b) Find limit of the above sequence.

Comment: I edited your question.  Please review it to make sure I did not make any mistakes in representing your question.

Comment: **To the community:** stop downvoting questions without explaining to the OP what you think they should improve.  The rest of us aren't mind readers to know why you downvoted, and it wouldn't kill you to actively contribute in improving the content once in a while rather than just downvoting.